# Pick nested type of optional property?

Tags: typescript

I have a problem with picking type...

```js
type GetWorkspaceListDto = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    code: string;
    info: string;
    user: {
      id: string;
    };
    workspaceLicense?: {
      id: string;
      type: "FREE" | "STANDARD" | "PREMIUM";
      quota: number;
      beginDate: Date;
      expireDate: Date;
    };
    workspaceUsersCount: number;
  };
```

I just want to pick 'type' property from workspaceLicense, which is optional.

```js
Pick<GetWorkspaceListDto["workspaceLicense"], "type">
```

but I got error.

```
Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'never'
```

how can I get it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here you have:

```js
type GetWorkspaceListDto = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  code: string;
  info: string;
  user: {
    id: string;
  };
  workspaceLicense?: {
    id: string;
    type: "FREE" | "STANDARD" | "PREMIUM";
    quota: number;
    beginDate: Date;
    expireDate: Date;
  };
  workspaceUsersCount: number;
};



type Result = Pick<NonNullable<GetWorkspaceListDto["workspaceLicense"]>, 'type'>
```

You should use `NonNullable` since, `workspaceLicense` can be undefined